# how many bytes in typical a firebase node

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Roughly, how many bytes of data are stored in the Firebae Real time database for a node such as?

```
{ Johnny {Age: 20, FavoriteColor: "Blue, ProfileImage: "RealllyyylongURL", isActive: true},}
```

How many come from integers, strings, long strings, Bools, etc. Does it matter if it is nested deeper?

I am just curious for pricing and data usage for mobile users. Firebase currently charges $5/GB/Month and I want to know if I am paying $.000001 of $.001 for each piece of information I store.

Thank you!

Comment: Using this one, https://mothereff.in/byte-counter I get 92 bytes with that.

Comment: So each character = 1 byte of data?

Comment: Something like that Ryan.

Comment: more info https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size

Comment: @FewFlyBy Firestore is completely different from firebae realtime database....